# How do I set a cmake policy?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to compile the Paraview graphical visualization software for my ARM-based laptop; however, I am getting a few configuration warnings that seem to relate to cmake 'policies'. The warning text and the cmake man page suggest that I should be able to run the command `cmake_policy()` to set a particular policy; however, I can't figure out how or where to run it.

How can I set a particular cmake policy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The CMake command `cmake_policy()` is documented in [the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_policy.html).

It is usually added to the `CMakeLists.txt` file of the project to change the behaviour of CMake itself, usually to be able to handle older `CMakeLists.txt` features with newer versions of CMake.

You may use it to set an individual policy using

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP<NNNN> OLD)
```

where `<NNNN>` is a CMake policy number and where `OLD` indicates that you want the "old behaviour" of this policy (the word `OLD` could also be `NEW`).

Or, you may use the command to set policies for compatibility with a particular version of CMake using

```
cmake_policy(VERSION x.xx)
```

where `x.xx` must be at least `2.4`.

In either case, the `CMakeLists.txt` file of the project is modified, and `cmake` will have to be re-run.

See also the documentation for [`cmake_minimum_required()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html#command:cmake_minimum_required).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, is NEW the default for policies, unless overridden? Also, it seems like any policy changes tend to be more for a specific project, rather than 'global' settings, is that correct?

Comment: @Time4Tea I think that you are correct on both points.  `NEW` exists to allow toggling policies on or off for specific parts of a `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Is there a way to do it from command line? Namely with `cmake ...`?

Comment: @Royi Yes, you can set `CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP<NNNN>` on the command line, e.g. `-DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0063=NEW`.

Answer (score 6):

I use Cmake version 3.22.0 and @kusalananda answer did not fix the issue for me. I added the following line to the top of `CMakeLists.txt` and the issue was fixed:

```
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP<NNNN> NEW)
```

Of course, `NNNN` should be replaced with the number given in the command line.

Answer (score 4):

The CMake policy warnings at the end explicitly inform users that they should not concern themselves with the messages. The messages are there for the project developers.

```
CMake Warning (dev) at c/tools/CMakeLists.txt:22 (add_executable):
  Policy CMP0069 is not set: INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION is enforced when
  enabled.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0069" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION property will be ignored for target
  'msgr-recv'.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

Use `-Wno-dev` to suppress it.

However, sometimes as a user of a software, you have a good reason to set a policy when you are installing the project. One reason might be to enable the link-time optimization (also called interprocedural optimization). Without setting a policy, CMake will ignore the `-DCMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION=ON`.

In such a case, you can use [`-DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP<NNNN>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMPNNNN.html) to get the behavior you need, without editing CMakeLists.txt. Of course, contacting the developer, suggesting that they deal with the policy in source, is a good practice.

```
-DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0069=NEW -DCMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION=ON
```